# Update existing table with additional data from different tables procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table `WebSummary` which has summary data from different tables that collect data continuously. I have to create a procedure that adds the new data from those tables to the `WebSummary`.

I have the draft, which I'm not sure if it's correct, but how could it be modified to insert only new data, because the old data is already there.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE WebLogTransfer 
AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * INTO #transfer FROM (

SELECT cast(LogDate AS DATE) LogDate, LogUser, LogPCName, [Log222ID], Count(*) LogCount
FROM [IS3].[ApplicationAccessLog].[dbo].[WebAppLog]
GROUP BY cast(LogDate AS DATE), LogUser, [Log222ID], LogPCName

UNION ALL

SELECT cast(LogDate AS DATE) LogDate, LogUser COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, LogPCName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, [Log222ID] , Count(*) LogCount
FROM [IS2].[ApplicationAccessLog].[dbo].[WebAppLog]
GROUP BY cast(LogDate AS DATE), LogUser, [Log222ID], LogPCName

UNION ALL

SELECT cast(LogDate AS DATE) LogDate, LogUser, LogPCName, [Log222ID], Count(*) LogCount
FROM [IS1].[ApplicationAccessLog].[dbo].[WebAppLog]
GROUP BY cast(LogDate AS DATE), LogUser, [Log222ID], LogPCName

UNION ALL

SELECT cast(LogDate AS DATE) LogDate, LogUser, LogPCName, [Log222ID], Count(*) LogCount 
FROM [IS].[ApplicationAccessLog].[dbo].[WebAppLog]
GROUP BY cast(LogDate AS DATE), LogUser, [Log222ID], LogPCName

ORDER BY 1
) a


INSERT INTO [IS3].[ApplicationAccessLog].[dbo].[WebSummary] (LogDate, LogUser, LogPCName, Log222ID, LogCount) 
    SELECT LogDate, LogUser, LogPCName, Log222ID, LogCount
    FROM #transfer 

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
  END 

COMMIT TRAN

DROP TABLE #transfer


END
GO
```

Should there be a `JOIN`, or `IF EXISTS`, or some point which would mean - data was transferred to this point and next time it will be transferred from that point?

Your knowledge would really help me on how to write an efficient procedure.

Comment: Probably using a `not exists where NewRecord.Log222ID = OldRecord.Log222ID`. Out of interest how do you ensure that each server has unique values for `Log222ID`?

Comment: It you explain the Log222ID allocation method I might have an idea.

Comment: You can use [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to do so.

Comment: Either use Merge as mentioned by Leszek Mazur or use a left join to your existing table and insert only the records where the left join columns are NULL. Either way: you need some kind of unique identifier for your records, such as LogDate + LogUser or something. Furthermore you have to decide, if you only want new records or changed records as well. If you need changed records as well, in case of the insert with left join you will have to add columns like "action" (insert, update) and "actiontimestamp" (when did the action happen) - otherwise you will receive duplicate records

Comment: While merges and joins would work, I'm not sure how well they would perform. Having a date cutoff point for the last transfer would be perfect, then you just select records more recent than the last transfer. Depending on your ID arrangement, if they are automatically incrementing, you might be able to do something where you select IS's greater than the last ID you transferred. However more information is required to be able to assist further.

Comment: Log222ID is computer system ID, corresponds to an application name. The column doesn't help here...